# Can data be transmitted from one object to another one during electrostatic discharge (ESD)?

Tags: electricity, information

Did this ever happen to you?, after you touch something (or someone) 'Ouch'! you get a static electric shock.

Can (any kind of) [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) be transmitted between two people during accidental electrostatic discharge (ESD)?

Why touching other people gives you (and them) a shock?

Comment: More on static electricity and shocks: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+static+electricity+shock

Comment: I propose a kind of Morse coding in which I sequentially charge a door handle to either high or low voltage and you grab it between charges...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. Part of the reason for this is because the brain's neural pathways and the dendrites of neurons are not compatible with the data transmission through electrical impulses.

Electricity moves to the path of least resistance. When you touch another person after receiving a buildup of static electricity, the other person becomes the path of least resistance, and this is why the shock occurs as the static electricity transfers to the other person.

Funny question, although I'm not sure it's entirely physics related. I would avoid sharing this incorrect theory to anyone with any sort of paranoia. Their brain may explode (metaphorically).